# SSIS 2008 R2 Package variable not assigned during run time in production

Tags: ssis

We have ssis 2008 R2 packages which works fine in UAT but not in Prod. Both the environments are 2008 R2 only.

During run time the data we are storing in one variable of object type(IN JSON FORMAT) . This is properly assigning in UAT but in prod this is not assigned properly and returns object reference error. The ssis packages are having same version in both environment. Even though data exists, it's not assigned to object type variable. Not sure why in prod.

Note : we have ssis package deployed in 64 bit in both environment.

Is there any setting we need to do.
We are trying to reproduce the same in UAT but we don't see any object reference error.
Could you please help.

Thanks,
PN

Comment: How are you assigning the variable? Are you using the `/SET` property of the command line/sql agent job step? Is this through configuration - if so, what configuration method are you using (dtsconfig, database,  environment variable, parent config and something else I don't remember)  If you take the same json value and use it in UAT, exactly, does it reproduce the error?

Comment: Reading the data from oledb source and in script component we are assigning the data to object type variable in json format. We r using database table configuration. That data is assigned during run time for corresponding record. Not Reproducing in UAT.